# Regular expression for an alphanumeric string of 10 characters

Tags: regex, django

I need to compose an expression for the urls.py file

The get-variable var can be an alphanumeric string of 10 characters.

The link looks like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=fea40u7b94
```

Comment: What regex's have you tried? You haven't provided us with any attempt at answering this yourself.

I suggest using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help yourself answer this one. Look into quantifiers and character groups

Comment: Edge case: what happens if a URL encoded character is contained within this?

Lets say there is a url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=%66%65%61%74%32%38%33%38%39%31` - This translates to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=feat283891`, but how would the regex handle that? Would you want it to handle that?

Some more examples would be great

Comment: What should be the workflow when 2 vars are provided to the url? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=feat283891&othervar=fea40u7b94`

Comment: I try it url(r'^(?P<var>\w+{10})$',

Comment: I need only one variable

Comment: Then my answer will cover what you need. Use the capture group to get the variable, with url encoding, or without url encoding.

Comment: You can't catch a GET variable in an urlpattern. Use `request.GET.get('var')` in your view.

Comment: refalmp, thanks a friend, this is a useful tip

Comment: Kyle Fairns, thank you my brother! You have helped me a lot and I will choose your answer best. But I do not understand why my question is being pushed?

Comment: @MyNick, From what's been given in the question, there are a lot of questions that could be asked (as with the edge cases I provided). On SO, we also expect an amount of code that has been tried, before answering, so we can get a better idea about what the asker is hoping to have answered. You provided that in the comments, but it isn't visible to all who look at the question without further reading. Have a look at the [info section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) of the regex tag to find out more, but I think I've covered the majority of the reasons for downvotes on this question.

Comment: thanks! And how will it be in the urls.py? url(r'^([&?]var=((?:%[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|[^&%]){10})(?:&|$))$', so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, when you add edge cases, it gets slightly more complicated, so I'll provide an answer to this one:

```
[&?]var=((?:%[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|[^&%]){10})(?:&|$)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2b0c4X/2)

Basically, this will match "var" at any point in the parameter process, without matching "othervar=", it will make sure to grab url encoded characters as a single char, and will make sure that it isn't grabbing a partial "var" (say the information is 11, or 20 characters long, this will not match that string, as it checks for another parameter after it, or the end of the string).

Breakdown:

- `[&?]var=` - `var=` must occur after an `&` or a `?`
- `%[\dA-Fa-f]{2}` - match a hexcode after a percentage sign (to get url-encoded characters as a single character).
- `[^&%]` - anything not a percent or ampersand
- `(?:%[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|[^&%]){10}` - non capture group, get the hexcode or not percent or ampersand exactly 10 times
- `((?:%[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|[^&%]){10})` - capture what I explained in the last point
- `(?:&|$)` - end at an ampersand or the end of the string or line

Answer (score 1):

You can group the request string values for `var`

```
>>> import re
>>> s
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=fea40u7b94&xyz=ewewv7832h'
>>> re.findall('=(\w{10})',s)
['fea40u7b94', 'ewewv7832h']
>>> re.findall('var=(\w{10})',s)
['fea40u7b94']
```

Comment: What about `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?othervar=fea40u7b94&xyz=ewewv7832h`? This will happily match that, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Keerthana, thanks, I'll try it. But I do not understand why my question is being pushed? I do not know much English. What I wrong asked?

Comment: Hi nick, here in stackoverflow, we basically try to solve the problem on our own and ask here when we are stuck. In your question, you didnt share the piece of code that you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try this one in your code.

`/(?<=var\=).{10,10}(?=$)/g`

Comment: This will match absolutely anything after any equals. What if it isn't a "var" that has been provided? They've also asked for a character limit of 10 (always exactly 10 characters), and this will accept any number of characters.

Comment: There are other edge cases not mentioned in the question, such as "othervar", which this would be a match for and what if there are other parameters also included in the url? What about url encoded characters (even though they don't have to be at all, there is every possibility that they could be)